Power Automate - Unable to send an email using outlook account's alias
I need to send an email using Power Automate.
For that - client already had one email e.g. abc-mail@xyz.onmicrosoft.com which has a two below email address aliases:

no-reply@xyx.onmicrosoft.com
no-reply@xyz.in

In Dynamics 365 F&O this no-reply email is already in use and working in expected. But I am facing an issue while using it with Power Automate.
I have attached screenshots below the implementation I have done in Power-Automate.

Goal: User should be receiving email from "no-reply..." email address


Question: Do I need to fix the Shared mailbox settings or Power Automate flow needs a fix?

In power automate I tried sending email with both approaches:

Send an email using Shared Mailbox (V2)

Tried passing the alias email in 'Original Mailbox address' as highlighted below



Send an email

By setting it in From (Send As)







